# Can async functions accept and execute callback functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've been really intrigued about `async / await` syntax recently and I've been experimenting with it for a while.
In this particular problem, my goal is to execute the callback function after all the promises are made, if possible.

I had no idea how to apply my ideas in real life situations so I expected the function to look like this.

```js
function endTask (task) {
   // finalizes tasks 
}

var taskCompleted = false; 

async function doSomething (callback) {
   const response = await fetch(some_url);
   const task = await response.json(); 

    if (task) { 
     taskCompleted = true; 
    }
   if (typeof callback == "function" && taskCompleted) {
   callback(task); 
}
}

doSomething(endTask);
```

Comment: no reason why not - without any detail in your code I can't see a problem

Comment: This is just an example code for demonstration only. I  just wanted to see if it's okay to put callbacks into async functions.

Comment: @HongQuanVi His point was that as you're using it now there's no issue with a callback (and as noted in the answer it doesn't make much sense). `async` functions are just functions.

Comment: Geez thanks for the good clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you already used async/await, maybe you don't need to use callback anymore. The purpose of async/await functions is to simplify the behavior of using promises, and avoid callback hell too.

Hope the example below could help.

```js
function endTask (task) {
   // finalizes tasks 
}

async function doSomething (callback) {
   const task = await fetch(some_url).then(res => res.json())；
   return task;
}

async function main() {
  const task = await doSomething();
  if (task) { 
    endTask()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the async/wait functionality is to reduce the complexity called [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/). Async functions effectively removes the necessity of passing around callback functions.

However, one can still pass a callback function to an async function as a reference to be called later in his logic. This is perfectly alright as long as the developers do not go to the extent of wrapping Promises around async functions. That application goes against the concept of async/await.

Async functions always take parameters in real practice and some of them are callback functions which are to be called immediately or pass on to another function.

Shorthand version of your code:

```
function endTask (task) {
   // finalizes tasks 
}


async function doSomething () {
   const response = await fetch(some_url);
   const task = await response.json(); 

   if (typeof callback == "function" && task) {
      endTask (task); 
}
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, `async` functions can take and call callbacks just like any other function, but that pretty much defeats the purpose of using an `async` function. There are some cases where there is a valid reason to do this (see Dave Newton's comment below), but this isn't one of them.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
function endTask(task) {
  // finalizes tasks 
}

var taskCompleted = false;

async function doSomething() {
  const response = await fetch(some_url);
  const task = await response.json();

  return task;
}

doSomething()
    .then(task => {
        if (task) {
            taskCompleted = true;
        }
        endTask(task);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle error
    });
```

Comment: A valid use of CBs in async functions is as CB "middleware", e.g., pluggable points of functionality *within* the async function. In the OP's example, as you state, not much point.

Comment: no, you should not do something like this. Using promises directly kind of defeats the entire purpose of using async/await

Comment: @gman It's much better than passing in a function with side effects to an async function just so the async function can call it when it's done. That's just pointless spaghetti. There's nothing wrong with mixing async functions and promises. They're two sides of the same coin. If you have a better way to do this, by all means let us know. Of course, the calling code could be made `async`, but it has to come back to promises at some point.